# Gridview with textboxes and SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on a web app using Visual Studio and VB.net. I have a grid view with textboxes. When I try to get the string from the textboxes of each row to update my database, it is empty though there is something in.

I want to know why
Here is the declaration of the textboxes in the gridview ;

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TpNote">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="TpTextBox" runat="server" width="50px"   BorderWidth="0px"></asp:TextBox>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>



            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CiNote">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="CiTextBox" runat="server" width="50px"   BorderWidth="0px" AutoPostBack="False" CausesValidation="False" ClientIDMode="Inherit"></asp:TextBox>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>


          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CfNote">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="CfTextBox" runat="server" width="50px"  BorderWidth="0px"></asp:TextBox>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

And here is the code behind:
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim rqt1, rqt2, rqt3, rqt4 As String

```
    con.Open()


    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Try




        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows




            Dim t As TextBox
            Dim ccNote As String
            t = CType(row.Cells(i).FindControl("CcTextBox"), TextBox)
            ccNote = t.Text




            Dim t1 As TextBox
            Dim tpNote As String
            t1 = CType(row.Cells(i).FindControl("TpTextBox"), TextBox)
            tpNote = TextBox2.Text


            Dim t2 As TextBox
            Dim ciNote As String
            t2 = CType(row.Cells(i).FindControl("CiTextBox"), TextBox)
            ciNote = t2.Text
            MsgBox(t2.Text)




            Dim t3 As TextBox
            Dim cfNote As String
            t3 = CType(row.Cells(i).FindControl("CfTextBox"), TextBox)
            cfNote = t3.Text


            Dim matricule As String
            Try
                matricule = GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text
            Catch ex As Exception


            End Try


            i = i + 1






            rqt1 = "Update INSCRITMODULE set CcNote ='" + ccNote + "'  where  (INSCRITMODULE.Matricule)='" + matricule + "'"


            rqt2 = "Update INSCRITMODULE set TpNote ='" + tpNote + "'  where  (INSCRITMODULE.Matricule)='" + matricule + "'"
            rqt3 = "Update INSCRITMODULE set CiNote ='" + ciNote + "'  where  (INSCRITMODULE.Matricule)='" + matricule + "'"
            rqt4 = "Update INSCRITMODULE set CfNote ='" + cfNote + "'  where  (INSCRITMODULE.Matricule)='" + matricule + "'"




            Dim commande1 As New SqlCommand With {
                .CommandText = rqt1,
                .Connection = con
            }
            commande1.ExecuteNonQuery()


            Dim commande2 As New SqlCommand With {
              .CommandText = rqt2,
              .Connection = con
          }
            commande2.ExecuteNonQuery()


            Dim commande3 As New SqlCommand With {
              .CommandText = rqt3,
              .Connection = con
          }
            commande3.ExecuteNonQuery()


            Dim commande4 As New SqlCommand With {
              .CommandText = rqt4,
              .Connection = con
          }
            commande4.ExecuteNonQuery()




        Next
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception


    End Try




End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show some of your code to explain what you have tried.

Comment: I've added it thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first debug the code and try to  make sure if each asp textbox value is coming  to t1,t2,..... to backend and then we can figure out rest of the thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
I would suggest,
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TpNote">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TpTextBox" runat="server" width="50px"  
Text ='<%#Eval("CCNote")' BorderWidth="0px"></asp:TextBox>
               </ItemTemplate>
              <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
  similarly bind values all textboxes which you want to get value in code behind.
 and then find textbox and get its value
```